# Android Studio Coding

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My task is to convert an activity to a fragment.

I did some changes but it still doesn't work. I am missing something, but I can't figure it out. One problem I do see is that the public class QuoteFragment extends SingleFregmentActivity is underline...not sure what I forget to do. Help please!

When I wan converting the activity to a fragment what did I forget?

Code for the activity...

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
* Main activity for the application.
 * Displays a series of quotes
 */
public class QuoteFragment extends SingleFragmentActivity{
/** Key for fact about author stored in Intent sent to AuthorFactActivity. */
public static final String EXTRA_AUTHOR_FACT =
        "edu.andrews.cptr252.stephanien.quoteoftheday.author_fact";
private static final String KEY_QUOTE_INDEX = "quoteIndex";
/**ImageView used to display inspirational image*/
private ImageView mImageView;

private TextView mQuoteTextView;
private TextView mAuthorTextView;
private Button mNextButton;

/**Quotes used in app */
private Quote[] mQuoteList = new Quote[]{
        new Quote(R.string.quote_text_0, R.string.quote_author_0,
                R.string.author_fact_0, R.drawable.mountain_pic),
        new Quote(R.string.quote_text_1, R.string.quote_author_1,
                R.string.author_fact_1, R.drawable.lier),
        new Quote(R.string.quote_text_2, R.string.quote_author_2,
                R.string.author_fact_2, R.drawable.math),
        new Quote(R.string.quote_text_3, R.string.quote_author_3,
                R.string.author_fact_3, R.drawable.smiley),
        new Quote(R.string.quote_text_4, R.string.quote_author_4,
                R.string.author_fact_4, R.drawable.th),
};

/** Index of current quote in list */
private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

/** Launch activity to display author fact */
private void displayAuthorFact(){
    //Create intent with name of class for second activity.
    //This intent will be sent to the Activity Manager in the OS
    //Which will launch the activity.
    Intent i = new Intent(QuoteFragment.this, AuthorFactActivity.class);
    //Add extra containing resource id for fact
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_AUTHOR_FACT, mQuoteList[mCurrentIndex].getAuthorFact());
    //Send the intent to the activity manager.
    startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * Remember the current quote when the activity is destroyed
 * @param savedInstanceState Bundle used for saving identity of current quote
 */
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //Stored the index of the current quote in the bundle.
    //Use our key to access the value later.
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_QUOTE_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
}

/**
 * Setup and inflate layout.
 * @param savedInstanceState Previously saved Bundle
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
    //mQuoteTextView.setText("This should generate an error. Do you see why?");

    //Re-display the same quote we were on when activity destroyed
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_QUOTE_INDEX);
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    //Display that text for the quote
    mQuoteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quoteTextView);
    int quote = mQuoteList[mCurrentIndex].getQuote();
    mQuoteTextView.setText(quote);
    mQuoteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayAuthorFact();
        }
    });

    //Display the author of the quote
    mAuthorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.authorTextView);
    int author = mQuoteList[mCurrentIndex].getAuthor();
    mAuthorTextView.setText(author);
    mAuthorTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayAuthorFact();
        }
    });

    //Display image
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_pic);

    //set up listener to handle next button presses
    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // move to the next quote in the list
            //if index reaches end array,
            //reset index to zero (first quote)
            mCurrentIndex++;
            if(mCurrentIndex == mQuoteList.length){
                mCurrentIndex = 0;
            }
            updateQuote();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
/** Display the quote at the current index. */
private void updateQuote(){
    int quote = mQuoteList[mCurrentIndex].getQuote();
    int author = mQuoteList[mCurrentIndex].getAuthor();
    int picture = mQuoteList[mCurrentIndex].getPicture();
    mQuoteTextView.setText(quote);
    mAuthorTextView.setText(author);
    mImageView.setImageResource(picture);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quote, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: I rewrote what I need help with.

Comment: The underline probably indicates a compiler error.  If you hover your mouse over it, or better yet just try to compile the code, you should see the text of the error.  It will probably help you figure out what the problem is; if not, [edit]ing the full text of the error into your question will help us help you.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom `QuoteFragment extends SingleFragmentActivity` is the problem. It isn't a Fragment.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create `QuoteFragment`
2. Copy-paste code from `QuoteActivity`
3. Remove `setContent(R.layout.activity_quote)` and implement `onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` method
4. Initialize views in `onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` method
5. Rename `activity_quote.xml` to `fragment_quote.xml`
6. Create xml file `activity_quote.xml` and add the `QuoteFragment` as a content:

   ```
   <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.QuoteFragment"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```

   See details here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout
7. And remove all code from `QuoteActivity` except of:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think you answer was a little vague based on the [new questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4468064/stephanie-nieman-ducky) following this answer.